# How to define a Model with fields filled by other data sources than database in django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

Does anyone can tell me if it's possible to create a Model class, with some model fields and some other fields taking their data from external data sources. The point is that I would like this model to be exploited the same way as another model by ModelForm for instance. I mean if I redefine "objects" Manager of the model by specifying the actions to get the datas for special fields (those who may not be linked to datas from the database), would the modelForm link the input with the fields not attached to the database ? Similar question about related objects. If I have a Model that has a relation with that special Model, can I get this Model instances through the classic way to get related objects (with both the classic model fields and the non-database fields) ?

Please tell me if I'm not clear, I'll reformulate.

Thanks.

EDIT: I tried to make a Model with custom fields, and then override the default Manager and its functions: all, get, ... to get objects like it would be with classical Model and Manager, it works. However, I don't use QuerySet, and it seems that the only way to get ModelForm, related objects and the admin functionnalities, working with it, is to build the QuerySet properly and let it being returned by the manager. That's why now I'm wondering if it's possible to properly and manually build a QuerySet with data got from external sources, or tell django-admin, model forms and related objects to take care of another class than queryset on this Model.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The way is to [define custom methods](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#model-methods):

> Define custom methods on a model to add custom "row-level"
>   functionality to your objects. Whereas Manager methods are intended to
>   do "table-wide" things, model methods should act on a particular model
>   instance.
>
> This is a valuable technique for keeping business logic in one place
>   -- the model.

Comment: I agree, this may work for setting and getting datas in fields. However, I would like to keep the abstraction provided by the Manager system. I was wondering if defining the logic on a new Manager may permit me to see ModelForm or related objects handling well work, and I think the solution you talk about may not do the stuff here.
If I'm wrong feel free to correct me.

Thank you for your answer.

Comment: As I know, django ORM is not ready to mix custom methods (or fields) and database fields in your queries. Where do you come from? From MS EF and linq? regards.

Comment: Thanks for your answer I'll try with and without Managers and I come back to give my feedback. I don't come from ms ef or linq. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

I have now a partial solution. I override the Manager and in particular its all() and get() functions (because I only need those functions for now). all() returns a queryset in which I added the result of some logics that give me objects build from external datas (taken through xmlrpc in my case). I added those objects to the qs through _result_cache attribute.
I think it's not clean and in fact my Model is now a custom Model and I don't have any database field. I may use it to fill database Models... However I can use it the same way as classic models:  MyModel.objects.all() for example.

If anyone has another idea I'd really appreciate.

Regards